# I can't figure out the issue with my UNION query

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

This is what I'm using:

```
SELECT [Contact ID], [Contact], [Zip Code], [County]
FROM [Training WLS]

UNION

SELECT [Contact ID], [Contact], [Zip Code], [County]
FROM [WLS TA]
```

This is the error:

> Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'Contact ID'.

Comment: You should tell us which database you are using.  I'm guessing either SQL Server or Access.  That being said, I don't actually see anything wrong with your query, assuming you really are using one of those two databases.

Comment: Have a look at this and see if it's relevant: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/932994/you-receive-an-error-message-when-you-run-a-query-in-microsoft-access

Comment: Yes sorry i'm using Access

Comment: try to use ticks instead of brackets  like SELECT\`Contact ID\`, \`Contact\`, \`Zip Code\`, \`County\`
FROM \`Training WLS\`

Comment: What do your tables look like?

Comment: If `Training WLS` and/or `WLS TA` are queries (not tables), check that they work by themselves.

Comment: The issue might be that you haven't specified which table the columns belong to. Use `[Training WLS].[Contact ID]` and adjust other columns similarly

Answer (score 0):

My guess?  The engine's not smart enough to Union columns that have spaces in the names.

Try this instead, and see if it works:

```
SELECT [Contact ID] as ContactID, [Contact], [Zip Code] as ZipCode, [County]
FROM [Training WLS]

UNION

SELECT [Contact ID] as ContactID, [Contact], [Zip Code] as ZipCode, [County]
FROM [WLS TA]
```